# UItextView with Custom font return Bold text for particular text

Tags: ios, objective-c, fonts, uitextview, bold

I have a TextView With some text with it.

```
TextviewFirst.text = @"La confirmation de été envoyée à";
```

And I have Set TextFont in storyboard to Raleway Font with Regular property. 
Here my expected output was[all the letters should be in regular style] : La confirmation de été envoyée à

but my actual output was like: those special characters are in **é** **à** **Bold** and other letters are in regular style.

what would be the Problem is ?
[image: attached screenshot]

Comment: Can you attach a screenshot? @Vicky_Vignesh

Comment: are you using ttf file? if yes, please post somewhere  the ttf... I think your font is like that only...

Comment: can u show ur tried code

Comment: It is possible that the Raleway Font does not support the special characters. He could use another font to correct it. He might found the correct letters but the font type is messed up. @Fahim is right. Use a .ttf file and check if it contains your special characters. If it doesn't, just add them.

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik : [take a look at this please](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42222838/find-circle-s-positions-in-image)